# Send messages FCM XMLHttpRequest cannot access control Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, xmlhttprequest, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Error code:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access

**Code:**

[image]

How to set header?

Comment: You should paste actual lines of code into the question. Use the [edit] button to improve the question.

Comment: *How to set header?* — First gain access to the server hosting `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.` This will probably require getting Google to hire and trust you

Comment: @HenryDev — It's `0`. It is always `0` when that error message is reported.